# Can Julia (julia-lang) code be statically analyzed to avoid run-time type errors?

Tags: julia

I recently ported one of my simulations to Julia and I discovered several type errors only *at run-time*.  I wish to statically analyze my Julia code. MATLAB has a similar problem in only finding many errors at run-time.

The only tool I found ([TypeCheck.jl](https://github.com/astrieanna/TypeCheck.jl)) performs a small subset of the static analysis that I would expect from a compiler.

Is there a static analyzer for Julia scripts so I can avoid many of what are now run-time errors?

Is there something that I could use with the LLVM JIT compiler? (I don't know much about how the Julia compiling works and what is and isn't possible)

Is this even possible due to the nature of Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the answer depends on which kind of run-time error you want, since Julia's compile-time occurs at a point in time that most compiled languages would call run-time.

If you type the inputs of all of your functions and also type all of the variables in all of your functions, you'll be able to get a lot of type errors at Julia's compile-time.

Comment: So my confusion is that the docs suggest that type declarations are not necessary, but then you'll (potentially) have (many) run-time errors just like most dynamically typed languages. And like you said, if you declare all the types, you can get compile-time checking.  For me, that is frustrating because at that point I no longer need the polymorphism (and I might as well have used Fortran).

Comment: What would your preferred alternative be?

Comment: Perhaps a mode where Julia will assume that every type is from a small family of types that have know conversions (so when it sees a complex double vector it will know its okay to convert it to a complex double matrix).  Within such a restricted type mode it could optimize everything and give me warnings if it had to guess a lot for a specific conversion. Then, with those assumptions, it could then do a lot of static analysis. 

I'm hoping for the speed of a statically typed Julia without having to declare **all** of the types. Thus maybe a type-family mode.

Comment: I think you should raise the issue on the mailing list, especially if you think you could implement a demo that would work.